# Replicar base de datos PostgreSQL local a la nube

Tags: postgresql

espero me puedan ayudar.

Tengo un sistema que estoy pensando migrar a PostgreSQL y me gustaría que esta base de datos se replicara en un servidor en la nube para poder ver reportes en tiempo real de cada sucursal vía web.

La pregunta es, alguien me puede orientar en como replicar una base de datos PostgreSQL de una caja Windows a un servidor Linux montado en la nube.

Desde ya muchas gracias

Comment: ayuda windows lice mobil 20217